# Core Data NSManagedObject Leak Cycle shown in Instruments – what does this mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, memory-leaks

I'm running the Xcode leaks Instrument against my app in the simulator (note I'm not running the allocations instrument).

When I select to view Leak Cycles I get loads looking like this:

[image: Core Data Leak Cycle]

The code the stracktrace is pointing to is:

`player.club = newClub`

In my app a Player belongs to a club and I'm just updating it to be a new one.

Both `Club` and `Player` are NSManagedObject.

- A player belongs to a club
- A club has_many players

Additionally when a Player moves club a new `TransferHistory` is created (also NSManagedObject)

- A transfer history has a player
- A transfer history has to_club and a from_club
- A club has many `transfers_bought` (inverse: "TransferHistory.to_club")
- A club has_many `transfers_sold` (inverse:
  "TransferHistory.from_club")

But there is no mention of the `TransferHistory` in Instruments.

Does anyone have any ideas what this image is saying?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong with so little information. Can you show surrounding code? What is the type of `club` property? Does it have an inverse relationship, and if it does, what type of a property it has?

Comment: A club does have an inverse relationship. I've updated my question with additional info on the model.

Comment: There's not enough information here. Core Data doesn't have any leaks I'm aware of itself, so any leaks would be in your code, which we need to help you.

Comment: The Instruments cycle view in the image shows some Core Data private methods. The framework probably does memory management in its own special way (because if it wasn't, there would be retain cycles everywhere - note that inverse relationships are represented as `retain` properties!). So I wouldn't care much about this image. The problem is probably somewhere in your code. Do you have custom setters? Or maybe you use blocks dealing with `Player` / `Club` instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I narrowed this issue down to other has one relationships in my schema.

Specifically a Player has one TeamSheetSelection and a TeamSheetSelection has one Player.

Before assigning the Player to a new Club. I manually set both of these has one relationships to nil.

```
Player.team_sheet_selection.player = nil
Player.team_sheet_selection = nil
```

Once I made this change the Player objects were no longer hanging around in memory.